# Am I interpreting the following ASME Section I section correctly

Tags: structural-engineering

Am I understanding the following PG.29.3 section of the code correctly.

**"When a head, dished to a segment of a sphere, has a flanged-in manhole or access opening that exceeds 150 mm** in any dimension, the thickness shall be increased by not less than 15% of the required thickness for a blank head computed by the above formula, but in no case less than 3 mm additional thickness over a blank head. Where such a dished head has a flanged opening supported by an attached flue, an increase in thickness over that for a blank head is not required. If more than one manhole is inserted in a head, the thickness of which is calculated by this rule, the minimum distance between the openings shall be not less than one-fourth of the outside diameter of the head."

I am only concerned with the bold section.

Are they saying that only access opening must exceed 150mm? Flanged-in manhole is exempt from this dimension?

The reason why I believe they are separate is because of the following paragraph.

Paragraph **PG-44** specifies that boilers have suitable openings, such as manholes, handholes, inspection openings, and washout openings. Elliptical **manholes shall not be less than 300 × 400** mm in size. **Circular manholes shall not be less than 380 mm in diameter**. Handholes shall not be less than 70 mm × 89 mm. There are no specific dimensions for other inspection or washout openings.

Inherently the flanged in man-hole will indeed be bigger than 100mm according to the above.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not understanding why it matters.  What would you do differently in a design if the 150 mm dimension does or doesn't apply in the case of a manhole?

Comment: boilers need openings, not all pressure vessels do, and other openings then accesses exist.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not.

Why do you think it says "only"?

Do you think it covers holes less than 150mm?

Basically it says " a flanged manhole greater than 150mm must have an increased thickness of 3mm minimum or 15% of the required thickness if that is greater.

Comment: Hi Mike. Thank you for your response. Mike, I provided more info as to why I think they are referred to as separate.

Comment: So where do you get 100mm from? Have you misread the first para you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

"Are they saying that only **access opening must exceed 150mm**?"

No, the provision has not set 150 mm as the minimum for either type of opening. It says "when ....has a flange-in manhole or access opening **that** exceeds 150 mm...the thickness shall be....", which means "when an opening in exceeds 150 mm, it requires...".